# how to solve the sparkSession class not found in intellij project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, bigdata

While submitting scala spark project I am getting this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

After many repeated attempts I am not able to solve this problem. Can anybody help me to submit my project

I have tried revalidating the cache and submitted the project still not solved

Comment: [Create a “Hello World” project with sbt](https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/index.html#create-a-hello-world-project-with-sbt) [Open hello-world project using IntelliJ](https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/index.html#using-intellij)

Comment: Try to create [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) project and open it in IntelliJ rather than plain Scala (no-sbt) IntelliJ project. Make sure that you add `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.1"` (or your version of spark) to `build.sbt`.

Comment: I have added dependencies and now another error is coming

Comment: Please update the question (you can press "edit") i.e. what you're doing in details, what errors you get, how to reproduce step-by-step etc.

Comment: Are you opening/creating a project in IntelliJ (with or without `sbt`) or using `spark-submit`?